# iCalendar recurrence - Every sunday except last, even if the month has 4 or 5 Sundays

Tags: calendar, icalendar

I have an event that occur every sunday except last sunday.
Therefore, when the month has 5 sundays it'll occur 4 times and when the month has 4 sundays it'll occur 3 times.

Considering that Exrule is deprecated in RFC 5545, what is the best way to represent this in iCalendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=-5SU,-4SU,-3SU,-2SU

Comment: Thank you very much @anmari !